# in the code snip below, the compiler won't compile

Tags: java, operators

code will not compile

```
byte a = 127;
byte b = 1;
byte c;
c = (a + b); //eror
System.out.println("The value of c=" + c);
```

the compiler won't compile the code.

Comment: well you need the semi colons at the end of byte declaration

Comment: well i forgot to put the semicolons, but thats not where the problem is.. anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

Java stores numeric types as int by default. Try:

```
c = (byte)(a+b);
```

The error occurs because an integer (4 bytes) cannot be contained within a single byte without losing information, which is why the compiler requests that you make this conversion explicit.

---

Additionally, FYI - single short and byte declarations are actually stored as a single word in memory (which is 4 bytes), so you are not saving memory while restricting the size of the number. This is not the case with arrays, where each slot in an array of `byte` or `short` will actually have 1 or 2 bytes respectively.